# How to update rows based on other rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-manipulation

let me ask my question with an example. For example I have a dataframe like this:

```
DAY     A     B     
0       10    6
1       12    8
2       18    6
3       20    10
4       16    12
5       12    8
6       14    10
```

I want to change every column based on previous column. For example **in row 1 I want my A value as = (10+12)/2 * 5 = 55**. And same for B values and other rows. My desired dataframe should be like:

```
DAY     A     B
1       55    35
2       75    35
3       95    40
4       90    55
5       70    50
6       65    45
```

I need your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) for add shifted values by [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with divide by `2` and multiple by `5` and last remove first only `NaN` row by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.add(df.shift()).div(2).mul(5).iloc[1:]
print (df)
        A     B
DAY            
1    55.0  35.0
2    75.0  35.0
3    95.0  40.0
4    90.0  55.0
5    70.0  50.0
6    65.0  45.0
```

Or is possible use rolling `mean` with `2` for sum 2 rows with divide by `2`:

```
df = df.rolling(2).mean().mul(5).iloc[1:]
print (df)
        A     B
DAY            
1    55.0  35.0
2    75.0  35.0
3    95.0  40.0
4    90.0  55.0
5    70.0  50.0
6    65.0  45.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work. But I want to do this forward not backward. I mean values of DAY 1 should be 55 and 35 not DAY 0.
Shoud I use 1 instead of -1 on df.shift ?

Comment: @skbmoony - I notice it, so changed answer.